# How to manually trigger a upload file event on Dropzone

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, dropzone.js

I have Dropzonejs nicely integrated into my frontend (VueJS).

I have problem with Acceptance Testing Dropzone using Webdriver / Codeception. Bottom line is Webdriver NEEDS a file input so it can attach files too.

`<input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file"/>`

Any way to manually trigger a upload inside the dropzone instance? I can put a button on the page and trigger the upload inside dropzone but keep its functionality. This input would only render when my frontend configuration is set to <> PRODUCTION.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I just found out Dropzonejs appends a hidden input (.dz-hidden-input) to the body by default or werever you want using de hiddenInputContainer option.
That input is directly hooked into Dropzone, if you edit the source and make it not hidden and use it to pick files the queue process runs automatically. Thats what I need!

Problem is the input is Hidden and my test suite + selenium webdriver cannot interact with the input if its hidden. Any way to make it visible without altering default behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium can only work with file input via the $I->attachFile method. I dropped dropzonejs in favor of another solution (custom made) that implements a  and its all good now!

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

put in your test

```
$I->attachFile('input.dz-hidden-input', 'your_file.txt');
```